# Getting Error While importing files from the "react-native" package

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, error-handling, module

I got this little error recently where i was making a chatting app and created a component. I imported react from react and

```
import { View,Text,StyleSheet,TextInput,TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
```

but this was giving and development server 500 error saying

```
Error: Unable to resolve module  from C:\Users\User1\Desktop\app\Screens\File.js:  could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
  ..\node_modules
  ..\..\node_modules
> 1 | import { View,Text,StyleSheet,TextInput,TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
    |                                                                                 ^
```

any help would be supported please help me

I tried recreating the whole file again, but nothing worked.

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "welpme",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "expo": "~48.0.11",
    "expo-font": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "firebase": "^9.20.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.6",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^8.2.0",
    "react-native-fontawesome": "^7.0.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "react-native-eject": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```